# Powershell - Active Directory - filter PasswordLastSet by today

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following powershell it works without the filter. However, if I want to see whether passwordlastset was today it throws an error. I am trying to compare the date (without the time).

This line throws error:

```
Get-ADUser -identity svc-sap-dataRead -ldapfilter passwordlastset=get-date -properties passwordlastset

Get-ADUser -identity svc-sap-dataRead -properties passwordlastset

DistinguishedName : CN=svc-sap-dataRead,OU=Service Accounts,OU=SAP-
                    OG,OU=Applications,OU=Prod-Groups,DC=csi,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         :
Name              : svc-sap-dataRead
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : dcbadba0-3cd7-4e51-9d14-d0e8a6be17f5
PasswordLastSet   : 5/6/2016 8:44:13 AM
SamAccountName    : svc-sap-dataRead
SID               : S-1-5-21-3791487480-1111548175-1301309645-519760
Surname           :
UserPrincipalName : svc-sap-dataRead@csi.com
```

Just tried the following code: it does not error nor gives me anything back.

```
Get-ADUser -identity svc-sap-dataRead -properties passwordlastset |
where {$_.passwordlastset -eq (get-date)}|select-object passwordlastset, name
```

Comment: Get-ADUser -identity svc-sap-dataRead -properties passwordlastset |
where {$_.passwordlastset -lt (get-date)}|select passwordlastset, name  this syntax works. is there a way to ignore time from both passwordlastset and get-date so that -eq works that way i am intending to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're comparing the full DateTime, not just the day. In other words, you're comparing down to the minute. Put this in your `where` block:

```
$pw = $_.passwordLastset;
$pw.ToShortDateString() -eq $(Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
```

edit: Here's the full command:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity svc-sap-dataRead -Properties passwordLastSet | Where-Object {
    $pw = $_.passwordLastSet
    if ($pw -ne $null) {
        $pw.ToShortDateString() -eq (Get-Date).ToShortDateString()
    }
} | Select-Object passwordLastSet, Name
```

Your `Where-Object` is going to filter out users that don't meet the criteria in that block, in this case, users who haven't reset their passwords today.

If you just want a boolean value of whether they've reset their passwords today you might try something like this:

```
$adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity svc-sap-dataRead -Properties passwordLastSet | Select-Object passwordLastSet, Name
$pw = $adUser.passwordLastSet
$resetPasswordToday = if ($pw -ne $null) { $pw.ToShortDateString() -eq (Get-Date).ToShortDateString() } else { $false }
```

This is getting the passwordLastSet attribute, seeing if it's null and if not seeing if it's date is today.
(Keep in mind, if you manually expire a password by checking the "User must change password" box, this essentially makes `passwordLastSet` null.)

Comment: It looks like $pw is an object and i need to get the date out of this object. Anyone else know whats the method for that

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you need the date in a specific string format? The object is of type `DateTime` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. There are different ways to get the date out.

Comment: $pl = Get-ADUser -identity svc-sap-app -properties passwordlastset | select passwordlastset
write-host $pw
if($plw.ToShortDateString() -eq $(Get-Date).ToShortDateString())

I get an error at the if line

Comment: You might double check your variables, it looks like the don't match up. I edited my original response for clarity and to include a full example.

Comment: @langstorm. I used the latter method and worked like charm. thank you so much. I appreciate it.